# WPF c# Textblock Mouse Over Backgound Color in code

Tags: c#, wpf

Как задать background color у textblock в **коде** при наведение мышки на него.

Comment: есть триггеры, зачем вам в коде?

Comment: Писать WPF приложения в стиле WinForm плохая практика, лучше тогда просто WinForm использовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Wpf есть стили которые можно применять ко всем однотипным контролам. В App.xaml опишите следующие строки и все TextBlock-и примут красный задний фон при наведении мышью:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из прошлого вопроса, вы пишите через code-Bechind. Если без MVVM то так :

```
    <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextblock" Text="111" MouseEnter="TextBlock_MouseEnter" Background="White"
               MouseLeave="MyTextblock_MouseLeave" Width="100" Height="23"/>
```

в Code-bechind :

```
    private void TextBlock_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MyTextblock.Background = Brushes.AntiqueWhite;
    }

    private void MyTextblock_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MyTextblock.Background = Brushes.White;
    }
```

Имя элемента в разметке можно не указывать :

```
    private void TextBlock_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var TB = sender as TextBlock;
        TB.Background = Brushes.AntiqueWhite;
    }

    private void MyTextblock_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var TB = sender as TextBlock;
        TB.Background = Brushes.White;
    }
```

Comment: А с MVVM, можно как-то задать для всех TextBox эти параметры?

Comment: @fangry textblock  или  TextBox  ? просто добавьте обработчик каждому элементу.

Comment: TextBlock* опечатка

Comment: `lBox.Items.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = tarr[i], Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 0)),TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap});` Так я добавляю новый TextBlock

Comment: @fangry если вам не срочно могу ответить позже.

Comment: Ну, если не слишком заняты, можете сейчас помочь?